# In Javascript, How can I replace all blank lines in comments with other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the previous code

```js
/*


hello
*/


const x = 'test'
```

after replacement, it looks like this, **I just replaced blank lines in comments**

```js
/*
test
test
hello
*/


const x = 'test'
```

Comment: What is the replacement logic here?

Comment: Replace blank lines in /* */ with test. example above， I only replaced the blank line in the second line and the third line， But the blank lines on the sixth and seventh lines are not replaced

Comment: Just use an extended find and replace in your dev environment to replace `\n \n` with `\ntest\n` surely? (multi-line of course)

Comment: There are other blank lines outside /**/, I don't want to replace these outside blank lines

Answer (score 1):

We can try a regex replacement with the help of a callback function:

```js
var input = `/*


hello
*/


const x = 'test'`;

var output = input.replace(/(\/\*.*?\*\/)/gs, (x, y) => y.replace(/^\n/gm, "test\n"));
console.log(output);
```

The idea here is match every `/* ... */` multiline block comment.  We then pass each such match to a callback function which does a global replacement on `^\n`, which is every empty line, replacing with `test\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If the Javascript [supports a lookbehind assertion](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can assert `/*` to the left and `*/` to the right without matching any of those 2 strings in between.

Then you could match all empty lines, and replace with `test`

If there can also be spaces only, you can use `^[^\S\r\n]*$` instead of `^$`

- `(?<=` Postive lookbehind

  - `\/\*(?:(?!\*\/|\/\*)[^])*` Match `/*` and any char using `[^]` that is not directly followed by either `/*` or `*/`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `^$` Match an empty line
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:(?!\*\/|\/\*)[^])*\*\/` The same mechanism as the lookbehind, now matching `*/` at the end
- `)` Close the lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JCykOB/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=\/\*(?:(?!\*\/|\/\*)[^])*)^$(?=(?:(?!\*\/|\/\*)[^])*\*\/)/gm;
const str = `/*


hello
*/

a line here


`;
const x = `test`;
const result = str.replace(regex, x);
console.log(result);
```